# Using IPMItool to set system shutdown on upper critical temperature

Tags: dell, ipmi, ipmitool

x-post with Stack Overflow (which I'm now beginning to think was a mistake)

I've been digging quite a bit into IPMItool commands and have yet to find a comprehensive list of raw hex commands. We have approximately 90 Dell C6220 II machines that I need to set a trigger (Dell calls these Platform Event Filters) to have the system shutdown upon reaching the Upper Critical Threshold that I set (ironically with IPMItool) for inlet temperature. Our Dell rep tells me this isn't possible and that I'll have to pull up the web interface for all 90 machines and set this by hand. They also told me it wasn't possible to set the inlet temperature thresholds with IPMItool and I did that so my faith in Dell is dwindling. What little I've been able to find on the internet it looks like I might be able to make it happen with raw hex commands. Can anyone in the great internet wild help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the freeipmi tools ipmi-sensors-config and ipmi-pef-config. First I ran `ipmi-sensors-config -L | grep Inlet` to find which sensor number corresponded to the inlet temp (for my C6220 II machines it was sensor 16, but for my C6320s it was 110, or sometimes 10, so be sure to do this). I then ran `ipmi-sensors-config -c -e '16_Inlet_Temp:Upper_Non_Critical_Threshold=30' &&
ipmi-sensors-config -c -e '16_Inlet_Temp:Upper_Critical_Threshold=32'`. This sets the temps to what you want, but we're not done. We have to actually have to set an event to react to these. For that I ran `ipmi-pef-config -c -e 'Event_Filter_4:Event_Filter_Action_Power_Off=Yes' &&
ipmi-pef-config -c -e 'Event_Filter_5:Event_Filter_Action_Power_Off=Yes'`. Event 4 and 5 in my system corresponds to Temp Non-Critical and Temp Critical events for all temp sensors. To find these I ran ipmi-pef-config -o > pefconf.txt, and then used Vim to search for "Temp".